# Running a python script using schedule library

Tags: python, schedule

My company blocks the Windows Task Scheduler (along with many other Python libraries), so I need to use the `schedule` library. My script imports several flat files, performs some grouping and simple calculations using dataframes, and then saves one final TXT file. I've read up on how `schedule` works, but how do I use it to run the entire script?

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import schedule

def daily():
    
    #then do all dataframe creation/manipulation, group by's, concatenations, etc...
     
schedule.every().day.at("16:30").do(daily)
```

It doesn't error out, but it also doesn't do anything; it just states:

> do daily() (last run: [never], next run: 2023-09-08 16:30:00

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `do` function only registers the job, but it will not actually execute it. You need to use the `run_pending` function to execute the job.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import schedule

def daily():
    
    #dataframe creation/manipulation etc...
     
schedule.every().day.at("16:30").do(daily)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60)
```

The interval of 60 seconds should be sufficient for your case since you are working with minute-level time accuracy and not seconds.

---

##### [run_pending()](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#schedule.Scheduler.run_pending)

> Run all jobs that are scheduled to run.
>
> Please note that it is intended behavior that run_pending() does not
> run missed jobs. For example, if you’ve registered a job that should
> run every minute and you only call run_pending() in one hour
> increments then your job won’t be run 60 times in between but only
> once.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add something like this at the end to run your scheduled jobs:

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Also see [examples](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
# Keep the script running
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second
```